# Instantiating Haskell parametric data types

Tags: haskell

Trying to grasp Haskell `type parameter` below,

```
Prelude> data T a = C1 a | C2 (a -> a)

Prelude> :t C1 1
C1 1 :: Num a => T a

Prelude> :t C1 (+1)
C1 (+1) :: Num a => T (a -> a)

Prelude> :t C2 1
C2 1 :: Num (a -> a) => T a

Prelude> :t C2 (+1)
C2 (+1) :: Num a => T a
```

To my knowledge `C1 1` is out of question, `C2 1` makes no sense, `C1 (+1)` and `C2 (+1)` seem contradictive.

Why has none of the type checks above complained anything? Your enlightments are much appreciated.

Comment: In `:t C1 (+1)` the type a is `(Num t => t -> t)`

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, numeric literals are *polymorphic*:

```
1 :: Int
1 :: Integer
1 :: Double
...
```

Technically, this is obtained by the general type

```
1 :: Num a => a
```

So, "`1` can be of any type, provided that such type is of class `Num`".

When you do, e.g., `C2 1`, `1` is taken to be of the function type `a -> a`, and an extra constraint is generated to ensure that `a -> a` is a `Num`:

```
C2 1 :: Num (a -> a) => T a
```

Of course, a function is not a number. Why then there is no type error? Because in Haskell it is not forbidden to extend the `Num` class to include functions as well. You could do that with,
for instance:

```
instance Num b => Num (a -> b) where
   fromInteger n = \_ -> n
   x + y = \z -> x z + y z
   ...
```

effectively turning `1 :: a -> a` into a "constant one" function.

This could enable code such as (contrived example follows)

```
 case (some value of type T Int) of
 C1 x -> x
 C2 f -> (f + g) 50
 -- assumning g :: Int -> Int
 -- result is f 50 + g 50
```

If you do not provide the instance, then the code is not inherently wrong, since an instance might be added later. In such case, the constraint will stick around in your code, since it can not be discharged. If you try to convert the `T a` into any type not involving `a`, this requires to discharge the `Num` constraint, and at that time the compiler will indeed complain.

---

The cases involving `(+1)` can be explained by noticing that this is an *operator section*,
so it's not just a unary plus in front of 1. In particular,

```
(+1) means \x -> x + 1
```

so `(+1)` is actually the successor function.

Comment: Another example of this is if you try ``:t C2 "1"`` you will get a type error: ``Couldn't match expected type `a -> a' with actual type `[Char]'``. But if you enable OverloadedStrings you will get ``:t `C2 "1" :: IsString (a -> a) => T a``.

Comment: @chi, could you evolve practical yet simple example on the case `C2 1`? I began with `data T = C2 {get :: a -> a}`, but was stuck on `get . C2 $ 1` onwards.

Comment: @sof I've added a contrived example, but I do not think that adding a `Num (a -> a)` instance leads to any practical use. Indeed, I would recommend against it. I just mentioned it so that one can understand why the compiler does not complain.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have an error, create a situation, where `a` must be the same, like:

```
> :t [C1 (+1), C2(+1)]
Couldn't match expected type ....
```

In your example `a`s are different, like `a1` and `a2`. And no errors